# HTML image wont load?

Tags: html, image, directory, load

Why won't my HTML image load? It just shows a blue box that represents an image?

Here is my directory structure
[image]

And here is my code

```
<body>
<img src="ImageFolder/download.jpg">
<h1> Welcome to my smelly fish</h1>
</body>
```

Here are the errors from chrome

```
Refused to apply style from 
'http://localhost:3000/css/main.css' because its MIME 
 type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME 
type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
download.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server 
responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
 localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from ' 
  http://localhost:3000/css/main.css' because its MIME t 
 ype ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME 
 type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Comment: Could you give a little more information? An error, browser, et cetera? Is the code you show all of your code or do you have the `<!doctype html>`?

Comment: I have the doctype html, its not all of the code, and I am using express and nodemon running a local server

Comment: No errors on the local server